# pattern in max number of distinct prime factors of any number in [1,n]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

While solving a math-based programming [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/leonardo-and-prime/problem), I had to write a function to compute the maximum number of distinct prime factors for any number in the range $[1, n]$ for any number $n$.

I tested this function with some basic inputs, namely, the powers of $10$.

I noticed that for $n = 10^a$, this function outputs $a + 1$. In other words, the maximum number of prime factors for any number in the range $[1, 10^a]$ is $a + 1$.

Why is this true and does this pattern persist with higher powers of $10$? (I only tested upto $a=8$)

*PS: Please let me know if this the right way to present my question and if there are any ways to improve it!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number $k$ of distinct prime factors of a number $m\le n$ is attained when $m$ is the product of the first $k$ primes. So to find $k$, just keep multiplying successive primes until you reach a number greater than $n$.

Your conjecture remains true as long as the product of the first $a+1$ primes has $a$ decimal digits:
$$2\times3=6$$
$$2\times3\times5=30$$
$$2\times3\times5\times7=210$$
$$\cdots$$
$$2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19=9,699,690$$
But it fails for the first time at
$$2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19\times23=223,092,870$$
and is false for all higher values of $a$.

Comment: Thanks! That is actually the same algorithm that I am using in my function, multiplying consecutive primes together until the product goes over n.

Comment: However, I still don't fully understand the reason behind this. Is there any particular reason for the emergence of this pattern?

Comment: @sushant_padha: what pattern?

Comment: That the max number of distinct prime factors for any number upto 10^a is equal to a+1 upto a=8. Is there a reason behind this or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @sushant_padha: This is not a very special property. I don't think it needs any explanation.